# Kruskal-Wallis test in R, when comparing multiple groups with data not having a normal distribution

Tags: r

Hello stack overflow community,
I need help with the Kruskal-Wallis test in R. For a class in my masters, I needed to desgin and perform an experiment and analyse the data for a report. I'm new at R, so be nice :-) (I know it's not a code writing service)
For my experiment, I wanted to test influence of water temperature on oxygen flux in two macroalgae. My data does not have a normal distribution and I am comparing oxygen flux for the three temperatures 15, 20 and 30C.
I'm stuck with the R analysis, I'm not sure if I need to pivot_longer before conducting the Kruskal-Wallis test. Does anyone have experience with this test? How do I prepare my data for this test?

[This is how my data is set up. Species, temp and oxygen flux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCM5L.png)

I tried to pivot my data longer by
pivot_longer(
cols = c(15, 20, 30),
names_to = c("Temp"), values_to = "Flux"

and no luck
I also tried running the test with no data prep and it will change characters into numeric values, so I assume it changed the species names to numeric values (I dont know how) and the p-value I got was very very low

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064). Where is your actual code to run the test?

Comment: Your data looks like it is in a nice, tidy, long format already, I doubt you need to `pivot_longer()` for any reason.

Comment: Regarding your test, have you read the `?kruskal.test` help page and run the code examples at the bottom? The Description says: *"performs a Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test of the null that the location parameters of the distribution of x are the same in each group (sample). The alternative is that they differ in at least one."* It would help us help you if you can more clearly indicate the hypothesis you want to test in terms of the test--do you want to do one test to see if the (mean) oxygen flux is the same for all species at all temperatures?

Comment: Or do you want to run separate tests for each species, acknowledging that species might have different flux, but to see if it also depends on temp? Or vice versa, separate tests for each temperature to see if there is difference by species for a given temp? Or something else?

Comment: Why should I not post data in images? I'm sorry, I was not aware of this

Comment: I want to test if there is a significant difference in oxygen flux across temperatures, 
so the null hypothesis is that there is no difference in oxygen flux between the temperatures. Maybe I should test the two species separately, however, I am also curious if there is a difference between species
And thank you so much for the help so far, as stated, I'm very new using R, but learning this program will be so useful